# Trying to perform a simple login but getting a error that i don't understand

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I am trying to perform a simple login without sessions. basically check if thedatabase has that username and password combination and let the user know if he got the combination correct or not. When submitting a username and password i get an error back.
Not sure what i am doing wrong, should be a simple process of checking if database has a username and password combination based on what the user has inputted.

Please any help would be great, thank you!

this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /Applications/MAMP/../..
```

This is my code

```
<?php
include_once 'classes/Connection.php';
class User{
    private $db;
    public function __Consrtuct(){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function Login($name, $pass){
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Loggingin WHERE username=? and password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $name);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->execute();
            if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                echo 'User verified, Access granted';
            }
            else {
                echo "Incorrect username or password";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo 'Please Enter username and password';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `__construct`. That is why the constructor is never called and `$this->db` is null.

Comment: And... doesn't the connection need dbhost, username, passwd etc? Or is it hardcoded in `dbConnect()`?

Answer (score 2):

__construct is spelled wrong...

```
public function __Consrtuct(){
    $this->db = new Connection();
    $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
}
```

Should be

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new Connection();
    $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
}
```